# Json Parsing using java

Tags: java, json

```
  8fd14735-b195-4c27-b99c-5bf1a2d35834 {
    "Slaves": "1",
    "kdt build Box Gen": "0.00323034008",
    "Job Render": "19.1420002",
    "Adaptation Luminance": "0.00553634018",
    "LightMan finalize PA": "6.93000004e-07",
    "GeomMan finalize Total": "0.163755",
    "IES bytes": "0"
  }
```

The above is the kind of data in my file.txt. I am trying to parse it through the json parse but i shows various exception.

```
{
  "Slaves": "1",
  "kdt build Box Gen": "0.00323034008",
  "Job Render": "19.1420002",
  "Adaptation Luminance": "0.00553634018",
  "LightMan finalize PA": "6.93000004e-07",
  "GeomMan finalize Total": "0.163755",
  "IES bytes": "0"
}
```

It only works when i try to parse the above shown lines within curly braces. I dont know the implementation to parse the file containing jobid and other fields between  curly braces which are in json format. I wrote the following code to parse the data within curly braces:

```
package com.journaldev.json;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.sql.Statement;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
//import java.util.Iterator;
//import org.json.simple.JSONArray;
import org.json.simple.JSONObject;
import org.json.simple.parser.JSONParser;
import org.json.simple.parser.ParseException;
public class FileInsert2 {

    private static final String DB_DRIVER = "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver";
    private static final String DB_CONNECTION = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/";
    private static final String DB_USER = "root";
    private static final String DB_PASSWORD = "root";
    private static final String dbName = "raas";

    private static final String jsonFilePath = "/Users/t_shetd/Meta.txt";
    public static void main(String[] args) throws ClassNotFoundException {
        JSONParser jsonParser = new JSONParser();
        try {
            Connection conn = null;
               Statement stmt = null;


                  //STEP 2: Register JDBC driver
                  Class.forName(DB_DRIVER);
                  //STEP 3: Open a connection
                  System.out.println("Connecting to a selected database...");
                  conn = DriverManager.getConnection(DB_CONNECTION + dbName, DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD);
                  System.out.println("Connected database successfully...");

                  //STEP 4: Execute a query
                 // System.out.println("Inserting records into the table...");

            FileReader fileReader = new FileReader(jsonFilePath);
            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(fileReader);
            String line = br.readLine();
            while(line != null) {

                JSONObject jsonObject = (JSONObject) jsonParser.parse(line);

                String c1 = (String) jsonObject.get("Slaves");

                System.out.println("Slaves: " + c1);

                String c2 = (String) jsonObject.get("kdt build Box Gen");
                System.out.println("kdt build Box Gen: " + c2);
                String c3 = (String) jsonObject.get("Job Render");

                System.out.println("Job Render" + c3);

    //KDTree Kickstart

                String c4 = (String) jsonObject.get("Adaptation Luminance");

                System.out.println("Adaptation Luminance: " + c4);



                String c5 = (String) jsonObject.get("LightMan finalize PA");

                System.out.println("LightMan finalize PA: " + c5);

                String c6 = (String) jsonObject.get("GeomMan finalize Total");

                System.out.println("GeomMan finalize Total: " + c6);
                String c7 = (String) jsonObject.get("IES bytes");

                System.out.println("IES bytes: " + c7);

                String c8 = (String) jsonObject.get("KDTree Kickstart");

                System.out.println("KDTree Kickstart: " + c8);


                String c9 = (String) jsonObject.get("Indirect Tree Build");

                System.out.println("Indirect Tree Build: " + c9);
                String c10 = (String) jsonObject.get("Average Cutsize");

                System.out.println("Average Cutsize: " + c10);

                String c11 = (String) jsonObject.get("cube_map count");

                System.out.println("cube_map count: " + c11);

                String c12 = (String) jsonObject.get("GeomMan finalize accel build");

                System.out.println("GeomMan finalize accel build: " + c12);



                String c13 = (String) jsonObject.get("Scene Setup Total");

                System.out.println("Scene Setup Total: " + c13);

                String c14 = (String) jsonObject.get("Downloaded bytes");

                System.out.println("Downloaded bytes: " + c14);

                String c15 = (String) jsonObject.get("Environment Tree Build");

                System.out.println("Environment Tree Build: " + c15);
                String c16 = (String) jsonObject.get("LC Preview");

                System.out.println("LC Preview: " + c16);
                String c17 = (String) jsonObject.get("Environment VPL Sampling");

                System.out.println("Environment VPL Sampling: " + c17);

                String c18 = (String) jsonObject.get("Geometry bytes");

                System.out.println("Geometry bytes: " + c18);
                String c19 = (String) jsonObject.get("Eye Sample Tracing");

                System.out.println("Eye Sample Tracing: " + c19);
                String c20 = (String) jsonObject.get("LightMan finalizeDirectional");

                System.out.println("LightMan finalizeDirectional: " + c20);

                String c21 = (String) jsonObject.get("Scene Setup Memory Profiling");

                System.out.println("Scene Setup Memory Profiling: " + c21);

                String c22 = (String) jsonObject.get("Target Generation");

                System.out.println("Target Generation: " + c22);

                stmt = conn.createStatement();
                //String sql = "insert into ras (Slaves, JobRender, AverageCutsize) values ('" + siteName + "', '" + render + "', '" + u8 + "');";

                String sql = "insert into ras (Slaves, JobRender, kdt_build_Box_Gen, Adaptation_Luminance, LightMan_finalize_PA, GeomMan_finalize_Total, IES_bytes, KDTree_Kickstart, Indirect_Tree_Build, Average_Cutsize, cube_map_count, GeomMan_finalize_accel_build) values ('" + c1 + "', '" + c2 + "', '" + c3 + "','" + c4 + "', '" + c5 + "', '" + c6 + "','" + c7 + "', '" + c8 + "', '" + c9 + "','" + c10 + "', '" + c11 + "', '" + c12 + "');";
                stmt.executeUpdate(sql);

                line = br.readLine();

            }

//          JSONArray names = (JSONArray) jsonObject.get("Names");
//
//          Iterator i = names.iterator();
//
//          while (i.hasNext()) {
//
//              System.out.println(" "+i.next());
//
//          }
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (ParseException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        catch(SQLException s){
            System.out.println(s.getMessage());
        }





    }

}
```

Please help me out to parse the whole content so that i can insert them in database columns. At present i am just able to split and insert the data between curly braces using json parser.

Comment: You should make sure you tag what language you are developing in (and you *don't* need to include that in the title!)

Comment: What kind of exceptions are you getting, and at which line?

Comment: Save yourself a lot of time and effort and just use a library to do the json parsing. I have had great success with Google Gson (https://code.google.com/p/google-gson/). You create Classes and map the json to them directly.

Comment: @WillieNel OP is already using a library to do the parsing. While I agree there are others, the OP is just doing it wrong.

Comment: You're reading in the file a line at a time: that's not going to give you valid JSON. Parse the entire file.

Comment: Building off of @DaveNewton use the [`parse(Reader)`](http://juliusdavies.ca/json-simple-1.1.1-javadocs/org/json/simple/parser/JSONParser.html#parse(java.io.Reader)) method and directly pass it the `FileReader` instead of reading a line at a time.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the JSON you're trying to process is an object with 1 field (8fd14735-b195-4c27-b99c-5bf1a2d35834) that has a value that is itself a JSON object. To get your code to work, you'd need to navigate to that object before getting the nested fields.

So if you do the following right after your call to `jsonParser.parse`, the rest of your code should work:

```
jsonObject = jsonObject.getJSONObject("8fd14735-b195-4c27-b99c-5bf1a2d35834");
```

Comment: Except that the OP is reading in the JSON file line-by-line, and parsing it the same way--which almost certainly will almost never work. I'm surprised they're able to get anything at all.

Comment: True. It would only work if the input file only has newlines after each object (which, since he says if he parses the other payload fine, I assume is the case and that the newlines above are just for readability).

Comment: (8fd14735-b195-4c27-b99c-5bf1a2d35834) is not json object , some other user edited it. its not as json object in my generated file. if it would have been json object than it was easy for me to parse through it.

Comment: @Dave Newton i tried to parse whole file but raise error of unexpected token at position 0 as 8fd14735-b195-4c27-b99c-5bf1a2d35834 is not a json object.

Comment: @dhruvsheth7 Well it's not; it should be in quotes. If you're getting invalid JSON back then you have a separate issue.

Comment: @Dave Newton, Its file generated from database. One field is JobID which is 8fd14735-b195-4c27-b99c-5bf1a2d35834 and other is metadata which is in the curly braces. I need jobid and all fields in braces as separate by parsing them.